# Two @ManyToMany in one class

Tags: playframework-2.2, ebean, playframework-2.3

I migrated my project from PF 2.2.X to 2.3.X and I have classes Project and Person

```
public class Project extends Model {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="project_manager")
    public List<Person> managers;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="project_customer")
    public List<Person> customers;
    ...
}

public class Person extends Model {
...
}
```

If I try to get managers or customers from Project instance, Ebean make 2 query to project_customer table. So I have same customers in both collections.

I think it's bug in Ebean 3.3.4 because it used to work fine in PlayFramework 2.2.X

How to work around? Any ideas? May be I can make PF 2.3 to use Ebean from PF 2.2?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935374/play-framework-ebean-two-manytomany-relations-return-same-data#comment50370716_30935374)